# Aiogram python InlineKeyboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot

I have some code:

```
master = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
master.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text='7(800)555-35-35', url='tel:+78005553535'),
           InlineKeyboardButton(text='8(800)555-35-35', url='tel:+88005553535'))
```

But when I try to summon this keyboard I have an error:
`aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Wrong http url`

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the code as follows:

**main.py**

```
from aiogram
import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import keyboards as kb

bot = Bot(token = 'BOT_TOKEN')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands = ['inline'])
async def show_items(message: types.Message):
   await message.answer('It is buttons', reply_markup = kb.start_keyboard)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates = True)
```

**keybords.py**

```
from aiogram.types
import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

inline_keyboard = InlineKeyboardButton(text='7(800)555-35-35', url = 'tel:+78005553535'),
InlineKeyboardButton(text='8(800)555-35-35', url = 'tel:+88005553535')

start_keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(inline_keyboard)
```

Comment: I am sure it would help the community if you explained to us why and how you code would solve the OP's problem